# Redirect url in barcode after scan

Tags: php, barcode

How can i redirect my barcode after scan in php?

I have written below code for barcode generation,

> index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Barcode</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Product Name or Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="barcodeText" class="form-control" value="<?php echo @$_POST['barcodeText'];?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="hidden" name="barcodeSize" id="barcodeSize" value="20">
                <input type="hidden" name="printText" id="printText" value="true">
                <input type="submit" name="generateBarcode" class="btn btn-success form-control" value="Generate Barcode">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['generateBarcode'])) {
    $barcodeText = trim($_POST['barcodeText']);
    $barcodeSize=$_POST['barcodeSize'];
    $printText=$_POST['printText'];
    if($barcodeText != '') {
         echo '<h4>Barcode:</h4>';
         echo '<img class="barcode" alt="'.$barcodeText.'" src="barcode.php?text='.$barcodeText.'&size='.$barcodeSize.'&print='.$printText.'"/>';
    } else {
         echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Enter product name or number to generate barcode!</div>';
    }
 }
?>
```

For generating barcode

> barcode.php

```
 <?php

 $filepath = (isset($_GET["filepath"])?$_GET["filepath"]:"");
 $text = (isset($_GET["text"])?$_GET["text"]:"0");
 $size = (isset($_GET["size"])?$_GET["size"]:"20");
 $orientation = (isset($_GET["orientation"])? 
 $_GET["orientation"]:"horizontal");
 $code_type = (isset($_GET["codetype"])?$_GET["codetype"]:"code128");
 $print = (isset($_GET["print"])&&$_GET["print"]=='true'?true:false);
 $sizefactor = (isset($_GET["sizefactor"])?$_GET["sizefactor"]:"1");

 barcode( $filepath, $text, $size, $orientation, $code_type, $print, $sizefactor );

 function barcode( $filepath="", $text="0", $size="20", $orientation="horizontal", $code_type="code128", $print=false, $SizeFactor=1 ) {
$code_string = "";
// Translate the $text into barcode the correct $code_type
// if ( in_array(strtolower($code_type), array("code128", "code128b")) ) {
    $chksum = 104;
    // Must not change order of array elements as the checksum depends on the array's key to validate final code
    $code_array = array(" "=>"212222","!"=>"222122","\""=>"222221","#"=>"121223","$"=>"121322","%"=>"131222","&"=>"122213","'"=>"122312","("=>"132212",")"=>"221213","*"=>"221312","+"=>"231212",","=>"112232","-"=>"122132","."=>"122231","/"=>"113222","0"=>"123122","1"=>"123221","2"=>"223211","3"=>"221132","4"=>"221231","5"=>"213212","6"=>"223112","7"=>"312131","8"=>"311222","9"=>"321122",":"=>"321221",";"=>"312212","<"=>"322112","="=>"322211",">"=>"212123","?"=>"212321","@"=>"232121","A"=>"111323","B"=>"131123","C"=>"131321","D"=>"112313","E"=>"132113","F"=>"132311","G"=>"211313","H"=>"231113","I"=>"231311","J"=>"112133","K"=>"112331","L"=>"132131","M"=>"113123","N"=>"113321","O"=>"133121","P"=>"313121","Q"=>"211331","R"=>"231131","S"=>"213113","T"=>"213311","U"=>"213131","V"=>"311123","W"=>"311321","X"=>"331121","Y"=>"312113","Z"=>"312311","["=>"332111","\\"=>"314111","]"=>"221411","^"=>"431111","_"=>"111224","\`"=>"111422","a"=>"121124","b"=>"121421","c"=>"141122","d"=>"141221","e"=>"112214","f"=>"112412","g"=>"122114","h"=>"122411","i"=>"142112","j"=>"142211","k"=>"241211","l"=>"221114","m"=>"413111","n"=>"241112","o"=>"134111","p"=>"111242","q"=>"121142","r"=>"121241","s"=>"114212","t"=>"124112","u"=>"124211","v"=>"411212","w"=>"421112","x"=>"421211","y"=>"212141","z"=>"214121","{"=>"412121","|"=>"111143","}"=>"111341","~"=>"131141","DEL"=>"114113","FNC 3"=>"114311","FNC 2"=>"411113","SHIFT"=>"411311","CODE C"=>"113141","FNC 4"=>"114131","CODE A"=>"311141","FNC 1"=>"411131","Start A"=>"211412","Start B"=>"211214","Start C"=>"211232","Stop"=>"2331112");
    $code_keys = array_keys($code_array);
    $code_values = array_flip($code_keys);
    for ( $X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++ ) {
        $activeKey = substr( $text, ($X-1), 1);
        $code_string .= $code_array[$activeKey];
        $chksum=($chksum + ($code_values[$activeKey] * $X));
    }
    $code_string .= $code_array[$code_keys[($chksum - (intval($chksum / 103) * 103))]];

    $code_string = "211214" . $code_string . "2331112";
// }
// Pad the edges of the barcode
$code_length = 20;

for ( $i=1; $i <= strlen($code_string); $i++ ){
    $code_length = $code_length + (integer)(substr($code_string,($i-1),1));
    }

if ( strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal" ) {
    $img_width = $code_length*$SizeFactor;
    $img_height = $size;
} else {
    $img_width = $size;
    $img_height = $code_length*$SizeFactor;
}

$image = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height + $text_height);
$black = imagecolorallocate ($image, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate ($image, 255, 255, 255);

imagefill( $image, 0, 0, $white );
// if ( $print ) {
//  imagestring($image, 5, 31, $img_height, $text, $black );
// }

$location = 10;
for ( $position = 1 ; $position <= strlen($code_string); $position++ ) {
    $cur_size = $location + ( substr($code_string, ($position-1), 1) );
    if ( strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal" )
        imagefilledrectangle( $image, $location*$SizeFactor, 0, $cur_size*$SizeFactor, $img_height, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black) );
    else
        imagefilledrectangle( $image, 0, $location*$SizeFactor, $img_width, $cur_size*$SizeFactor, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black) );
    $location = $cur_size;
}

// Draw barcode to the screen or save in a file
if ( $filepath=="" ) {
    header ('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
} else {
    imagepng($image,$filepath);
    imagedestroy($image);       
}
}
?>
```

Anyone please help me to redirect this barcode after scan

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not related to Magento